# How to use grpc bidirectional streaming in grpc-web?

Tags: streaming, grpc, grpc-web

I want to use grpc bidirectional streaming in web browser. Can I use bidirectional streaming with grpc-web in browser?

```
  rpc TypingStream (stream OutgoingTyping) returns (stream IncomingTyping);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no support for bidirectional streaming in gRPC-web.

You could follow the following thread if you're interested:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/24

Thanks :)

---

UPDATE (04/2023): In the latest streaming [roadmap](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/blob/master/doc/streaming-roadmap.md), it's decided that [WebTransport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebTransport) will be used for future support of bi-directional streaming in gRPC-Web.

Answer (score 0):

```
Remark: WebTransport is for HTTP/3 while this gRPC-web is for HTTP/2
        In fact, WebTransport want to be variant for websocket and is compatible with QUIC.
        WebTransport have streaming support and is bidirectional(client-server paradigm).
```